# html page very long

Tags: html, css

this is the css i have right now for the page,

```
.xyz {
        left: 400px;
        top: 55px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        width: 300px;
    }
    .m {
        left: 800px;
        top: -500px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        width: 300px;
        padding-bottom:100px;
    }
    .z {
        left: 1200px;
        top: -1153px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        width: 300px;
    }
    .main{background-color:white;opacity:0.6; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;
  margin-bottom:400px;text-align:center;width:30%;
    padding:20px;}
```

and this is the html code I have for the page right now. I updated it to include the body

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li style="float:left; padding-left:200px;font-size:30px;">HACKERYOU</li>
    <li style="padding-right:200px;">PART-TIME</li>
    <li>BOOTCAMP</li>
    <li>CONTACT</li>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>HOME</li>
</ul>
<nav class="main">
    <h1 style="opacity:1;">HACKERYOU</h1>
    <p style="opacity:inherit;">twenty-eighteen</p>
    <p style="opacity:1;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonum my nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
        dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper.
    </p>
</nav>
<p style="text-align:center;background-color:white;">FEATURED POSTS</p>
<div class="xyz">
    <img src="assets/image-small-1.jpg" height="310" width="300" />
    <p>HACKERYOU TECH TEST</p>
    <p>March 1st, 2018</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonum my nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
        dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p>
    <p>READ MORE</p>
</div>
<div class="m">
    <img src="assets/image-small-2.jpg" height="310" width="300" />
    <p>HACKERYOU TECH TEST</p>
    <p>March 1st, 2018</p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonum my nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
        dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
    </p>
    <p>READ MORE</p>
</div>
<div class="z">
    <img src="assets/image-small-3.jpg" height="310" width="300" />
    <p>HACKERYOU TECH TEST</p>
    <p>March 1st, 2018</p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonum my nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
        dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
    </p>
    <p>READ MORE</p>
</div>
</body>
```

and here is an image of the page
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdTmt.png)

why is the page so long? I don't understand why the length of the page is long, it shouldn't be that long for a test page

Comment: i don't see any <html> or <body> tag. Did you show us the full code?

Comment: You're using some **huge** pixel units for your measurements there (such as `left: 1200px`). The biggest problem is probably your `margin-bottom: 400px`. Use percentage-based units and much smaller pixel units, or your code will suffer tremendously on mobile devices. Remember, not all devices have screens that are at least 1200 pixels wide :)

Comment: updated to include the full body

Answer (score 1):

You using many selectors like that `top: -500px; top: -1153px;` etc with `postion: relative;`. When you use negative or positive value with `postion: relative;` element then the biggest issue that it take own place in screen and add `top, right` etc value. This is the main cause leaving huge space in bottom side.

However after see your effort and attempt I realized that you may trying achieve following result, please check on desktop size screen I wrote for you just as a guideline.

```css
.clearfix::after {
 content: "";
 clear: both;
 display: table;
}
.xyz, .m, .z {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 width: 300px;
 float:none;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 margin:20px;
}
.text-center {
 text-align:center;
}
.main {
 background-color:white;
 opacity:0.6; 
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-bottom:200px;
 text-align:center;width:30%;
 padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li style="float:left; padding-left:200px;font-size:30px;">HACKERYOU</li>
    <li style="padding-right:200px;">PART-TIME</li>
    <li>BOOTCAMP</li>
    <li>CONTACT</li>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>HOME</li>
</ul>
<nav class="main">
    <h1 style="opacity:1;">HACKERYOU</h1>
    <p style="opacity:inherit;">twenty-eighteen</p>
    <p style="opacity:1;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonum my nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
        dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper.
    </p>
</nav>
<p style="text-align:center;background-color:white;">FEATURED POSTS</p>
<div class="clearfix text-center">
<div class="xyz">
    <img src="assets/image-small-1.jpg" height="310" width="300" />
    <p>HACKERYOU TECH TEST</p>
    <p>March 1st, 2018</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonum my nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
        dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p>
    <p>READ MORE</p>
</div>
<div class="m">
    <img src="assets/image-small-2.jpg" height="310" width="300" />
    <p>HACKERYOU TECH TEST</p>
    <p>March 1st, 2018</p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonum my nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
        dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
    </p>
    <p>READ MORE</p>
</div>
<div class="z">
    <img src="assets/image-small-3.jpg" height="310" width="300" />
    <p>HACKERYOU TECH TEST</p>
    <p>March 1st, 2018</p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonum my nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
        dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
    </p>
    <p>READ MORE</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user9700458 if it provide your problem solution then please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here

```
   .main{background-color:white;opacity:0.6; margin-left:auto;
    marginright:auto;
    margin-bottom:400px;text-align:center;width:30%;
    padding:20px;}
```

Why are you giving main a margin-bottom of 400 pixels? Reduce it down to 40 and you will see that the page is shortened. I'm not sure what you are trying to do with this- but change it to a different value if you wish to reduce the page size

Comment: i did it and it still did not shorten, but thank you